# Adding TextLabels to ZedGraph so that all values are shown

Tags: zedgraph

When adding TextLabels to the X-Axis, zedgraph seems to insist on adding the labels each 10th step (So it seems). Explaination follows.

I have an array with values, based on some calculation. The first values in the array are on the following indexes; 8, 23, 39, 69 and 100
I have the x-axis set to Text

```
pane.X2Axis.Type = AxisType.Text;
```

Now if I do this:

```
pane.X2Axis.Type = AxisType.Text;
pane.X2Axis.Scale.TextLabels = monthValues;
pane.X2Axis.Scale.MinorStep = 5;
pane.X2Axis.Scale.MajorStep = 15;
```

The x2-axis doesn't show anything, where I want it to show all the values that are in the monthValues array, according to the curve.

If I do this:

```
pane.X2Axis.Scale.MajorStep = 8;
```

The x2-axis will now show the value at index 8, and if I do this:

```
pane.X2Axis.Scale.MajorStep = 23;
```

The x2-axis will show the value at index 23 and so on.

Obviously this is not desirable, so I wanted to know If anyone has an idea of what the real problem is, and how to fix it. I really hope someone can help me out, I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `min` and `max`for the X2Axis?

Also try `ChangeAxis` command